# Copy sql file over ssh with accents

Tags: ssh, mysql, scp, character-encoding, special-characters

I'm trying to migrate one database from server A to server B.

The database is mysql. This database has some records with character like ç, ã é, ...

The database encoding is UTF8

So on **server A** I export like this

```
mysqldump -u root -p sis > sis3.sql
```

Then I open the file (with `vi`) and the characters are not OK.
So I tried

```
 mysqldump -u root -p sis --default-character-set=utf8 > sis3.sql
```

Not OK yet. Then

```
 mysqldump -u root -p sis --default-character-set=latin1 > sis3.sql
```

And now the file *seems* OK.

#### The copy

The copy to server B is made from server B using

```
scp -i p root@0.0.0.0:/home2/sis3.sql ~/
```

But whenever charset I copy to server B, the file is never OK. the "special" characters are always wrong.

I tried to import on three ways (latin1, utf8, no default), all go wrong.

I import this way:

```
mysql -u root -p"pwdpwdpwd" --default-character-set=utf8 sis < sis3.sql
```

Of course, changing the default character set.

**But, as before I import to mysql the file is already "damaged", I think this probably caused over ssh transfer.**

Is there a way to transfer the mysql database without this problem?

### Servers Info

#### Server A

```
Linux version 2.6.32-5-amd64 (Debian 2.6.32-48squeeze6) (jmm@debian.org) (gcc version 4.3.5 (Debian 4.3.5-4) ) #1 SMP Tue May 13 16:34:35 UTC 2014
# locale
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US:en
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=pt_BR.UTF-8
LC_TIME=pt_BR.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=pt_BR.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=pt_BR.UTF-8
LC_NAME=pt_BR.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=pt_BR.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=pt_BR.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=pt_BR.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=pt_BR.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

#### Server B

```
Linux version 4.4.0-0.bpo.1-amd64 (debian-kernel@lists.debian.org) (gcc version 4.9.2 (Debian 4.9.2-10) ) #1 SMP Debian 4.4.6-1~bpo8+1 (2016-03-20)
# locale
LANG=pt_BR.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="pt_BR.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=pt_BR.UTF-8
LC_TIME=pt_BR.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="pt_BR.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=pt_BR.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="pt_BR.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=pt_BR.UTF-8
LC_NAME=pt_BR.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=pt_BR.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=pt_BR.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=pt_BR.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=pt_BR.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: You could try piping the file via ssh: `ssh user@remote "cat - > new_remote_file.sql" < local_file.sql`

Comment: Try computing a checksum on the file on both machines, to rule out the `scp` transfer as the source of your issues:  `md5sum sis3.sql`.

Comment: @user4556274 the checksum is the same... D=, so it's system-related

Comment: It's not clear to me that the data in the file created from your first `mysqldump` command is actually damaged. Just because `vi` and your particular terminal interpret it as ISO8859-n data rather than UTF8 doesn't automatically mean that `mysql` on the target server won't do the right thing anyway. Have you actually tried importing the original file and using it in the target application?

Comment: You can do character set conversion with a command like `iconv -f UTF-8 -t ISO-8859-15 < input.txt > output.txt` but I'm not yet convinced this is really necessary

Comment: I wrote "damaged" to not know what else terms to use. But I open both files original, and remote copy (over ssh on my machine), and they are visually different. So that's why I think the file was damaged, but it is not. Yes, I tried to import (on server B) that file and the result of select fetch wrong character, and the output of application was wrong too. Its important to say that in server A all things are just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found something that can be usefull to others

http://alexking.org/blog/2008/03/06/mysql-latin1-utf8-conversion

The thing is export as latin1 and change the file to "set NAMES utf8", as all of my tables are utf8.

Worked.

Answer (score 1):

1. Check that your terminal or terminal emulator is using *UTF-8* encoding.

   `locale` dumps the configuration of your shell, not of your terminal emulator.

   If you use `--default-character-set=utf8`, the output will be `utf8` encoded. So if your terminal (on server A) does not show it correctly, your terminal configuration is broken.

   E.g. in gnome-terminal menu, select `Terminal`, `Set Character Encoding`
2. If the md5sum checksum of the file, on server A and B, is identical, you can be "sure" that the file was correctly transferred.

Comment: I don't know If i understand correctly what you pointed. But I'm using Ubuntu 14 with a terminal instance with 2 tabs. If the problem were the terminal, and the checksum is the same, then it should be the same output for files, right?

Comment: Some terminal-emulator can use different encoding for different tabs but it is not very likely.

Answer (score 0):

Its got nothing to do with your terminal emulator.

> mysqldump -u root -p sis --default-character-set=latin1 > sis3.sql
>
> mysql -u root -p"pwdpwdpwd" --default-character-set=utf8 sis < sis3.sql

Import the file using the same charset you exported it with.

What you see in the exported file depends on the settings for the tool you use to view it. Don't confuse the issue - see how mysql interprets the data. If your backup is huge then do some experiments with a smaller dataset.

Presumably this is openssh? As long as you're not using some other software in the middle, the the file will not be modified in transit. You can verify this using md5sum or similar.

Comment: Even using the same charset the imported data is wrong.